# Where are array_ops.h and other C++ headers?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I'm writing a C++ application in TensorFlow 1.6.  I'm able to run Python files with no problems and have compiled the C++ examples that also run just fine, so I think I've set up TensorFlow correctly.

I've started a new project that builds with no errors using plain C++.  I'm now trying to construct `Placeholder()`, the docs say I need to `#include <array_ops.h>`, but it can't be located during compile. I did `sudo find / -name "array_ops.h"` and the only match was a file in `~/.cache/bazel`.

Is there an extra build/configure step needed to install the C++ header files referred to in the docs?

---

#### Solved

This is a bug in the documentation for 1.6.  The #includes listed in the API are not needed for calling some (many?) constructors.

Comment: g++ would like a `-I<path to header location>` to know where the headers are. Why? Because explicitly stating the location is unambiguous if you have multiple versions of a particular library on your system. You will likely also need `-L<path to library location>` and `-l<name of library>` on the command line to link in the libraries.

Comment: Sounds like you're missing a dependency. `array_ops.h` is a generated file, so you need to (transitively) depend on the corresponding rule that generates it. (See also [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9253)?)

Comment: I'm confused. You say the examples compile, but your code doesn't. And both use TensorFlow? Then it seems unlikely that the problem is with your TensorFlow installation. Can you identify the differences between the two pieces of code? Or show us?

Comment: Maybe the documentation is wrong.  I just noticed that the examples that call Placeholder don't #include array_ops.h and they compile just fine.

Comment: Please move your solution to its own answer, thank you.